# Getting ERROR 1064 (42000) in my stored proc

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

```
CREATE DEFINER=`name` PROCEDURE `storedProc1`(IN _id VARCHAR(50), IN _rowcount INT, IN _location VARCHAR(20))
BEGIN

    IF _rowcount IS NULL THEN
    set _rowcount = 1;
END IF;
```

Getting below error.

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5

Comment: IN _rowcount INT or IN _rowcount INT(10). Does any of these two syntax works?

Comment: You need an end to close the begin and set delimiters

Comment: Did you remember to use `DELIMITER //` (or similar) **before** attempting to define the procedure?

Comment: Hi Salmon, Thanks for replying. Here I have pasted a part of my stored proc. I have used END at the end of the stored proc.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the published code segment and I cannot reproduce your problem.